# How to limit allowed file size (multipart-file) in Ktor

Tags: kotlin, file-upload, multipartform-data, multipart, ktor

I'm wondering how to change allowed file size for multipart-files in ktor? 
I can not find anything in the documentation about this (only how to receive multipart-files). I'm using embedded netty server. I will limit filesize on the client but it would be good to also have that restriction on the server.

Searched the web and the only two things I found related to the topic is this example (seems to be configuration for a WAR file):
https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-samples/blob/master/other/maven-google-appengine-standard/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

and this example (how to receive multipart requests: 
https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-samples/blob/master/app/youkube/src/Upload.kt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing out-of-the-box, AFAIK.

But you can take inspiration from the official example:
https://ktor.io/servers/uploads.html

Note this part:

```
val bytes = read(buffer).takeIf { it >= 0 } ?: break
```

And also the fact that they count `bytesCopied`:

```
bytesCopied += bytes
```

So, you could do something like

```
if (bytesCopied > limit) { throw RuntimeException("Limit reached") }
```

That's what Apache Tomcat implementation does.

Comment: I'm not sure how everything works under the hoods so I assumed (if you look at the example in your link) that the whole data is already transferred to the server once it reaches that part of the code (loop in the example where the data is written to output stream). I will follow your advice thank you!

Comment: Streams are exactly for cases when you don't want all you data to be held in-memory.

Comment: Meanwhile you can use:     val contentLength = call.request.header(HttpHeaders.ContentLength)